# decompression algorithms that can work virtually without RAM (LZ like if possible)

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, compression

*edit: I try to rephrase this as to make this clearer the best I can :)*

I need to find a suitable way / choose a suitable compression to store a blob of data (say approx. 900KB) in a ROM where the available amount of free space is only about 700KB. If I compress the blob with some modern compression tool (eg. WinZIP/WinRAR) I can achieve the required compression easily.

The matter here is that the decompression will take place on a very VERY **VERY** limited hardware where I can't afford to have more than few bytes of RAM available (say no more than 100 bytes, for the sake of it).

I already tried RLE'ing the data... the data hardly compress.

While I'm working trying to change the data blob format so that it could potentially have more redundancy and achieve better compression ratio, I'm at the same time seeking a compression method that will enable me to decompress on my limited hardware. I have a limited knowledge of compression algorithms so I'm seeking suggestions/pointers to continue with my hunt.

Thanks!

*Original question was "I need info/pointers on decompression algorithms that can work without using the uncompressed data, as this will be unavailable right after decompression. LZ like approaches would still be preferred."*

Comment: Some specific question?

Comment: how is this supposed to work without using RAM ? Do you want to use EEPROM or disk ?!? Besides that your question is rather vague. Oh sorry: you didn't even provide a question, just facts.

Comment: I'm a newbie, please bear with me :)

Comment: It is supposed to run from ROM and compressed data is supposed to be in ROM too. Uncompressed data will be outputted, not retained.

Comment: With lack of memory the best shot for `LZ` type compression is to self-reference patterns in the un/decompressed data itself.

Comment: What type of data? What level of compression do you need? You might be able to get a so-so compression ration using Huffman or arithmetic coding, keeping the tables in ROM. Any sort of Lempel-Ziv approach would be impossible without RAM to store the decompressed data.

Comment: My data hardly compress with RLE, but it compress quite well (approx to 50% of the original size) using common LZ-based algorithm tools, which means there's at least some self-similarity, which I'd like to exploit.

Comment: The thing is without RAM, you cannot keep track of non trivial self-redundancy, but you can deal with **known** redundancy with a fixed dictionary stored in ROM.  Post the data you mean to compress.

Comment: Thanks for your help on the matter, guys. How could I have phrased my question so not to go off-topic? All I need was a suggestion of some decompression algorithm that I never heard of (which I believe are many!) so to keep my hunt on...

Comment: @sverx - I'm assuming you want some fixed amount of data pre-compressed into read only memory. You might want to update your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish. For text, you might want to also use some type of Huffman scheme, perhaps using only 6 bits for most characters, and perhaps a table of words. LZW requires using a stack for the decrompess, while a huffman / table scheme would need very little RAM.

Comment: @Weather Vane - please elaborate on that, sounds interesting. Are there already algorithms/tools for that?

Comment: @sverx that's the basic idea of LZ anyway. As Ross Ridge mentioned, you would still need a buffer of uncompressed data to use as a "library". The smaller the buffer, the less chance of finding repeating patterns. A proper implementation will build data structures for quick encoding, which also need RAM. I tried a method without that, searching the uncompressed data directly, but encoding was slow, although decoding was satisfactory. If your data is known, perhaps common patterns can be stored in ROM as suggested by other commenters.

Comment: @Weather Vane (and others too!): I'm reading about 'fixed' dictionary coding, and it might be suitable for my case. Unfortunately I can't find enough info on how to do that myself or if there are algorithms for this. Any hint? Or should I open a separate question? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is off topic because too broad.

LZW uses a sizable state that is not very different from keeping a slice of uncompressed data. Even if the state is constant and read from ROM, handling it with just registers seems difficult. There are many different algorithms than can use a constant state, but if you really have NO RAM, then only the most basic algorithms can be used.

Look up RLE, run length encoding.

**EDIT:**  OK, no sliding window, but if you can access ROM, 100 bytes of RAM give you quite some possibilities.  You want to implement this in assembly, so stick with very simple algorithms.  RLE plus a dictionary. Given your requirements, the choice of algorithm should be based on the type of data you need to decompress.

Comment: with -virtually- no RAM I meant consider this very very VERY limited, as in < 100 bytes so to say. Not enough for a sliding window, surely. RLE hardly compress my data, unfortunately, so I'm seeking some other method.